# ADO.NET for connecting Oracle Database on server

Tags: oracle, ado.net

Recently we have developed an application which connects to oracle database for fetching records. For fetching records, we are using OLEDB for Oracle. Application runs fine on my machine by connectng properly with Oracle ,since i have oracle client installed on my machine. Now i tried to test application on another machine, which doesnot have any oracle instance/Client installed on his machine. Application fails to connect to oracle central DB Server. Is it necessary for users to install oracle client on their machine before the application communicates with Oracle.

Here is Connection string

connectionString="Provider=msdaora;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XYZ)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=abc.com)));Persist Security Info=False;User Id=mahens; Password=XXXXXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SQLOLEDB"/>

The above code is for OLEDB for oracle. Is there any thing i required to install for connecting to central Oracle DB server from my windows application(.NET application installed on local machine).

If we try to use ODP.NET dll and include those dll's along within BIN directory,will that work?..Can any1 tell me a way wherein user need not install any oracle Client on their machine and communicate to server.

-Mahender

Answer (score 1):

I believe you always need the oracle client installed as everything in .net ultimately uses ODP.NET. However, you can use the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html) to make your users' setup process easier.