# C# connection string - Oracle 10g connectivity with IP address, port and sid

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I want to connect my WPF application with Oracle database, currently I have tried following connection strings, but these are not working.

I have:

> IP address: 172.16.9.18
>   Port: 1521
>   SID: SID10
>   User Id: Scott
>   Password: Tiger

I tried:

```
"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.16.9.18)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID10)));User ID=Scott;password=Tiger;"; //Not working

"Data Source=172.16.9.18:1521/SID10;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Scott;Password=Tiger;Unicode=True"; //Not working
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ help?

Comment: No, above solution is taken from there.

Comment: Do you get an exception? What does it say?

Comment: Do you have/need oracle client software installed? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268260/ado-net-for-connecting-oracle-database-on-server

Comment: Are you posting your credentials here?

Comment: I have oracle client installed, but I need to run it on that PC which is on LAN and does not have oracle client.

Comment: Since I am having Login form as first from for authentication, whatever the connection string is, i am getting following exeption- {"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MO_DO_File_Generator.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."} How can i get the exact exception?

Comment: "run it on that PC which is on LAN and does not have oracle client." -- from the thread I linked, I don't think this will be possible.

Comment: Can I use OleDb there to avoid installation of Oracle Client?

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like this:

```
public string GetConnString(string host,string port,string sid,string user,string pass)
{
   return String.Format("SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID={2})));uid={3};pwd={4};", host, port, sid, user, pass);
}
```